# Oculus Headset detached while oculus attached with the pc

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus

I am working on the Oculus project, The player character for my simulation in Unity.  in which I have firstperson controller, I have created game object of player in which I put FPCamera as a child and character's body.

**Issue:** When I attach my oculus camera it detached from the body and with the Oculus headset movement, FPcamera act as a separate view from the body. the body does not rotate and remain static even though FPcamera is moving according to the headset. However it works fine if I disable oculus and move the character with the mouse, I can see my body and move left right everything with all animations.
I have the following link for the oculus controllers  integrations in my project
https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/oculus-integration-82022 (Oculus integration)

here is a link which I have to achieve for my project, my FirstPerson should be like this in Oculus. you can see that the movement is with accuracy according to its headset movements
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7GpxsI-Tag

Note: I am using Unity 2017, there is no crash report in the project

Answer (score 0):

First of all send the correct link for the video please.

When i create a new scene and I want to implementate the oculus player,cameras and hands I make this:

1. Find "OVRplayercontroller" prefab and drag to the scene
2. Find "CustomHandLeft" and "CustomHandRight" and drag to the scene
3. Go to the child object in OVRplayercontroller>OVRcameraRig>TrackingSpace
4. Then selec the 2 hands
5. And drag the TrackingSpace object to the "Parent transform" property in the OVRGrabber script in the 2 hands

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

You can use **"OVRPlayercontroler"**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).